# Custom setter to be used in MapStruct

Tags: java, domain-driven-design, mapstruct

I have been looking through the [MapStruct documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/) without any success.

I am implementing a mapping between my Domain classes and my DTO classes; using *MapStruct*. In my domain, I do not want to use Setters for my fields because, we know that today **Setters are bad** (for many reasons, but that's not the topic of my question).

However when I want to convert `ItemDto` into `Item`, I got the following message :

```
Error:(17, 21) java: Property "name" has no write accessor in my.example.Item.
```

However my class `Item` has a Business method `void changeName(String newName)` that I would like to use in my Mapper.

The code of my Mapper is :

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(source="nameDto", target = "name")
    Item map(ItemDto dto);
}
```

My question is quite simple : how to specify StructMap to use  `changeName` as write accessor ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to implement something like that you would have to write your own custom `AccessorNamingStrategy`.

If your domain objects follow the same pattern `changeXXX` then a simple implementation can look like:

```
public class CustomAccessorNamingStrategy extends DefaultAccessorNamingStrategy {


    @Override
    public boolean isSetterMethod(ExecutableElement method) {
        String methodName = method.getSimpleName().toString();
        return methodName.startsWith( "change" ) && methodName.length() > 6;
    }

    @Override
    public String getPropertyName(ExecutableElement getterOrSetterMethod) {
        String methodName = getterOrSetterMethod.getSimpleName().toString();
        if ( methodName.startsWith( "change") {
            return IntrospectorUtils.decapitalize( methodName.substring( 6 );
        }
        return super.getPropertyName( getterOrSetterMethod );
    }
}
```

You can of course adapt the `CustomAccessorNamingStrategy` to fit your needs. Keep in mind that this would be used for all objects. Also the `ItemDto`.

More information about it can be found [here](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#_custom_accessor_naming_strategy) in the MapStruct documentation.

Comment: This solution works but seems to me not really solid. It is mapped on the name on the setter method and whenever I refactor the setter method, my compiler will not notice that. In any case, thanks a lot for your answer that I accept, even though I am not going to implement that.

Comment: What do you mean the compiler will not notice that? It is based on certain pattern that you might have in your code. MapStruct can give you compile errors if you forget to map something or if you are using an unknown property in `Mapping#target`

Comment: @fabien7474: If you did not implement the proposed solution, could you tell us what you did instead?